# Adding extra functions to an image's onmouseout attribute

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<img border="0" onmouseout="hidetips();" onmouseover="showtips();" src="image.gif">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("onmouseout", "hidetips();newfunction();");
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried above but it is not working, anyone one know how to add extra newfunction() at behind on the onmouseout attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mouseout` method to bind an event handler. Use an anonymous function to contain calls to the separate functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").mouseout(function() {
    hidetips();
    newfunction();
  });
});
```

Note: It will bind all found elements in the jQuery object, so you don't have to loop.

#### Edit:

You can bind the `showtips` function using jQuery also, so that you don't need the event attributes in every image element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").mouseover(showtips).mouseout(function() {
    hidetips();
    newfunction();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could add a function called `clickHandler` or similar which then runs as many functions as needed from there, so you are only specifying one function from `onmouseout` and `onmouseover`. For example:

```
<img border="0" onmouseout="clickhandler();" onmouseover="showtips();" src="image.gif">

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function clickhandler()
    {
        hidetips();
        newfunction();
    }
    function hidetips()
    {
        alert('hide');
    }
    function newfunction()
    {
        alert('newfunction');
    }
    function showtips()
    {
        alert('showtips');
    }
</script>
```