# How to hide ajaxtoolkit calendarextender when lost focus?

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

[image: calendarextender problem]Hi,

I want to hide first calendar when a second is open or when the calendar field lost focus. The issue is that if the user doesn't select any date from calendar and go to other control in page the calendar doesn't hide, only when user select any date from calendar the popup hides. This capture show the problem.

I see that in ajaxtoolkit calendarextender sample page the calendar control works fine, when out from one to another calendar prior popup hides but I don't find the sample code of this page. I think this page manage in javascript the event when the focus is lost, but I had found any sample code or project ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in addition, this problem only occurs when PopupButtonID property has a image control value. If I haven't any image button in order to open calendar popup its hide correctly when the focus is lost.

Comment: Can you use `ImageButton` instead of `Image` control for popup button?

Comment: You can try this hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883797/calendarextender-not-getting-hide-on-clicking-outside-the-calendar

Answer (score 2):

As Yuri mentions, using an ImageButton fixes this... or...

You need to handle the onmouseout event. You can do it this way:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1182269/4708411.aspx/1?Re+Calendarextender+and+Lose+Focus+Or+Mouse+Out

Or you could add some javascript (via jQuery) and inject an onmouseout event:

[Adding extra functions to an image's onmouseout attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897082/adding-extra-functions-to-an-images-onmouseout-attribute)

This is also shown in the forums.asp.net link, but  basically, on the onmouseout event you can just set the visibility of the calendar extender to hidden or none.

Comment: Thanks a lot dash and Yuiry!, only I replace Image for ImageButton control and works fine!!!

Answer (score 2):

As an option in addition to solutions provided by **dash**, you may use following decision if you don't want to use `ImageButton` instead of `Image` for PopupButton: set `OnClientShowing` properties on extenders to `"hideAnotherOpenedPoups"` and add onto a page script below.

```
// Array of BehaviorIds of each extender for those you use Image as PopupButton
var behaviorIds = ["CalendarExtender1", "CalendarExtender2"];

function hideAnotherOpenedPoups(sender) {
     for (var index = 0; index < behaviorIds.length; index++) {
          if (behaviorIds[index] !== sender.get_id()) {
               var extender = $find(behaviorIds[index]);
               if (extender.get_isOpen()) {
                    extender.hide.call(extender);
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following line of code to show the calendar on both Textbox and Image click.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onclick="showCalendar();" onfocusout="showCalendar();" ID="txtDate" />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="imgPopup" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" CssClass="MyCalendar" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" />
```

and add a javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showCalendar() {
       $( "#<%=imgPopup.ClientID %>" ).trigger( "click" ); //I've used .ClientID here just in case your page is inherited from a Master page
    }
    </script>
```

That should display the calendar when you click on the Textbox, and the calendar will be hidden once you click anywhere else on the form